# Inno Setup - File Copy

Tags: scripting, installation, inno-setup

I'm using Inno Setup with InnoTools Downloader and after the download completed I want to copy the downloaded file to the selected directory.

```
 if CurStep=ssPostInstall then begin
    FileCopy('Test.exe', ExpandConstant('{app}\Test.exe'), False);
```

It don't do anything, but if I restart the installer and I install again to the same folder, then it's copy the file. How is it possible or what I'm doing wrong? If I just do this, then it works properly each time:

```
 if CurStep=ssPostInstall then begin
    FileCopy('Test.exe', 'Test1.exe', False);
```

Comment: Specify the full path to the first parameter (`ExistingFile`) as well. Give it the full path where you downloaded your file. Otherwise you are expecting your source file to be placed in the current directory (path returned e.g. by the `GetCurrentDir` function).

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but can you tell me please how can I download the file directly to the selected directory? I'm adding the file to the downloader at this part: InitializeWizard, but I can't use the {app} here, because it's not yet initialized. Where is the code part after the path has been selected?

Answer (score 2):

I solved with using the `{src}` constant:

```pascal
// Add the file
itd_addfile('http://test.com/Test.exe',ExpandConstant('{src}\Test.exe'));

// Copy the file when it's finished the download
FileCopy(ExpandConstant('{src}\Test.exe'), ExpandConstant('{app}\Test.exe'), False);

// Delete the old file
DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{src}\Test.exe'));
```